# Which class to work with vector layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm doing different operations on vector layers.

Which class should I use for vector layer i.e QgsVectorLayer or QgsVectorLayerDataProvider?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following documentation and examples:

http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

and

http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html

Use QgsVectorLayer to open GIS files (or database layers) and QgsVectorDataProvider to get access to the features and their attributes.